# Usage of ReflectionUtils and BeanUtils for private fields

Tags: reflection, private, apache-commons-beanutils

I need to set some private fields in an object using another object's fields. Those two objects may not be instances of same class. 
What I see from a short reading, I can use Apache's BeanUtils and Spring's ReflectionUtils for that. I couldn't find a satisfying explanation for them regarding security, performance, support etc.
The solution will be used in production environment too, so I need a concrete solution.
Which approach do you suggest for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use just the BeanUtils library. See my sample, i do a copy properties from CustomerBean to SellerBean.

```
package testes.beanutils;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId((long)1);
    customer.setName("Bruno");
    customer.setLastname("Tafarelo");

    Seller seller = new Seller();

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(seller, customer);

    System.out.println(customer);
    System.out.println(seller);
    }
}

class Customer {

private Long id;

private String name;

private String lastname;

//getters and setters

//toString
}

class Seller {

private Long id;

private String name;

private int sales;

//getters and setters

//toString
}
```

Comment: Thanks but why? I'm looking for an answer explaining why I should use one but not the other. They both seem capable of doing your example.

Comment: Well. I can't explain about spring reflection, but i just do this api if springcore already  is dependency of my app. BeanUtils is small, simple, was used in many project like struts for example. BeanUtils, can make cache to speed up the reflection usage. The security, i know who can't set a property who a different type of the value, implicitly. I make use of BeanUtils, to parse form html (request parameters) to bean, i just can't populate a complex Collection, but simple lists and nested properties work well. Sorry i can't talk more or compare this libraries.